# Accessing magnetometer results in MPU-9250

Tags: imu, magnetometer

I am interfacing an MPU-9250 to an STM8S207 microcontroller.
The MPU-9250 is accessed via 400kHz I2C. I have no isses with getting measurement data from the temperature, gyro and accelerometer, but can not get the built-in AK8963 magnetometer measurement results.
I can read out the AK8963 device ID correctly, looks like the Fuse-ROM calibration values are correct, but when I program the 0x0A (CNTL1) mode register to 0x01 or 0x02 (single or 8Hz measurements), the DRDY flag never transitions to 1, and the CNTL1 register reads back 0x03, which is a reserved value.

Any ideas what I am missing?

The initialization sequence I'm using is below, after *configure_imu()* is called, reg 0x0A from the AK8963 reads back as 0x03.

```
void configure_imu()
{
u8 status, mag_mode, mag_sense[3];
i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 27,GYRO_FULL_SCALE_2000_DPS); // Configure gyroscope range  
i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 28,ACC_FULL_SCALE_16_G); // Configure accelerometers range  
i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 0x37,0x02); // Set bypass mode for external I2C master connection

i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 0x6B,0x01); // Clock source is PLLGYROZ
i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 0x19,0x04); // Set SMPLRT_DIV to 0x04; this gives a 200 Hz sample rate when using the DLPF
i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 0x1A,0x03); // 42 Hz LPF
i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 0x6A,0x01); // Disable master mode and clear all signal paths
//i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 0x37,0x32); // Interrupts pin stays high until cleared, cleared on any read, I2C bypass
//i2c_write_byte(MPU_I2CAddress, 0x38,0x01);                                        // Data ready interrupt enabled 

status = i2c_read(MAG_I2CAddress, 0x00, I2C_rx_rd_ptr++, 1);
if (status==0) return;  
i2c_write_byte(MAG_I2CAddress, 0x0B,0x01);  // Software Reset Magnetometer
Delay(10000);
i2c_write_byte(MAG_I2CAddress, 0x0B,0x00);  // Deassert Software Reset Magnetometer
Delay(10000);
do { status = i2c_read(MAG_I2CAddress, 0x0A, &mag_mode, 1); }
    while ((status==1) && (mag_mode>0));
i2c_write_byte(MAG_I2CAddress, 0x0A,0x0F);  // Enter Fuse-ROM mode
Delay(10000);
i2c_read(MAG_I2CAddress, 0x10, mag_sense, 3);   // Read the x-, y-, and z-axis calibration values
i2c_write_byte(MAG_I2CAddress, 0x0A,0x00);  // Enter power-down mode
Delay(10000);
i2c_write_byte(MAG_I2CAddress, 0x0A,0x02);       // Magnetometer to enter continuous 8Hz measurement mode

}
```

---

Thank you all for the comments! In the next version of the board I replaced the MPU-9250, however widespread it is, with a Bosch BMO055. It's little help if you are already committed to MPU9150/9250, but if board re-spin is still an option for you, I highly recommend the Bosch part. It has the Sensor Fusion engine built in, generating the acceleration / heading / quarternion information right outside the box without any MCU post-processing - which is actually what I needed.

Comment: Do you need to set up pass-through mode? "Pass-Through mode is also used to access the AK8963 magnetometer directly from the host. In this
configuration the slave address for the AK8963 is 0X0C or 12 decimal."

Comment: ThanksKrunal for you comment.
Pass-through mode is set up, and I can correctly read the WHOAMI hw ID register of hte AK8963.
I can also read factory calibration values from the fuse-rom, and read the correct MODE value (0x00) from (0x0A) after reset. However, once I write 0x01 or 0x02 to address 0x0A, instructing the magnetometer to provide a measurement sample, the data never becomes ready, and 0x0A reads back as 0x03.

Answer (score 1):

In case you still need the help, Have you tried reading the ST2 register every time also? There is a sentence in section 8.3.5. of the data sheet "Therefore, when any of measurement data is read, be sure to read
ST2 register at the end." 
I also had problems with the continuous modes, so I switched to triggered mode.

The two things solved my data problems with this chip.

Best of luck.
Tom